# Finding best routes using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I'm trying to find the best route through multiple points, considering traffic, speed limit, one way, and so on. ArcGIS online has Plan Routes functions which we only need to provide point feature class to get best routes that consider traffic and other variables. However, ArcGIS Pro does not provide that function. We have to use Network Analysis where we have to create network dataset first to have best routes that consider traffic and speed limits.

Is my understanding right ?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question. If you wish to also ask about QGIS then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Have you considered using Google map API?

Comment: Please read about that topic at this link : https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/arcgis-online-services.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Network Analysis Layer's "Find Best" sequence as explained here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/route-analysis-layer.htm Esri also provides a tutorial to follow here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/route-tutorial.htm